# Is there a way of increasing width of Action Bar drop down list

Tags: android, layout, spinner, android-actionbar

I have run though various scenarios and I haven't been able to find  a solution.

The issue arises when the orientation of the device is switched to landscape. The tabs become a spinner. The spinner isn't using the available space with in the action bar and it starts ellipsing the items, and visually it looks ridiculous as you can see:

***new users cant post images,users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks. you should inform the user before***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4miZ.png

switching to another item on the spinner for tabs:

i.imgur.com/I8PQ5.png

I was only able to find one built in style item for the action bar drop down list : android:**actionDropDownStyle** .

But it only seems to control whether to show a drop down or dialog
developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:spinnerMode
Even overriding the style and adding layout_width made no difference.

There is also no drop down item style like found in the spinner **android:spinnerItemStyle**. But the items are being styled based on the 
**android:actionBarTabStyle** and **android:actionBarTabTextStyle**, but overriding those styles and adding layout_width made no difference.

But after reducing the number of tabs from 3 to 2, the width increased.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7HSR.png

but clicking on the second tab, made the action bar switch back to spinner, but this time more spaced is used and completed is not ellipsed

i.imgur.com/3949m.png

It's as if the width of the spinner is being determined by the number of tabs. This does seem poorly done, it could be from the fact they are measuring if there is space to show the tabs bar. And when there isn't space, they are not recalculating the width available, and are just using the individual tab width they calculated earlier.

This was done on ICS, and with the display of title turned off, in the hope of increasing more width available for the action bar spinner.